# how to change styled(component) element

Tags: reactjs, element, styled-components

Having trouble changing the "section" into a div without touching the BaseGrid, the BaseGrid is in a different folder component, and I'm just importing it. If I use the forwardedAs='div' or as='div', it will render as a div but will not pass the default values that I still need from the BaseGrid.

How can I make it as a div and still get all the props that i need from the BaseGrid styled.section

```
const BaseGrid = styled.section `
....style here
`;
```

import {BaseGrid} from '/somefolder';

```
const SectionGrid = styled(BaseGrid).attrs({as: 'div'})`
..style here
`;

const SectionGrid = ({ forwardedAs, className, children, ...rest }: SectionGridProps) => (
    <BaseGrid forwardedAs={'div'} className={addClassName('section-grid', className)} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </BaseGrid>
);

const app () => {
return
<>
<SectionGrid />
</>
};
```

I'm trying to implement these but still not working

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask] and provide the necessary details. There are currently countless ways to interpret your question. Please also provide your expected result and what you got instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const ExtendMe = styled.div`
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const SomeImg = styled(ExtendMe).attrs({
  as: "img"
})`
  margin: 2em;
`;

const SomeDiv = styled(ExtendMe)`
  margin: 3em;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomeImg src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
      <SomeDiv>A div</SomeDiv>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You can refer:  https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop.

Comment: I think the OP already knows about this.

Comment: When I open my console, it does change to div, but it won't render the styling, which I still need the default styling coming from BaseGrid